# Client PC not booting when certain TFT plugged in - TFT or graphics card failure?

Tags: graphics

here comes something quite strange:
On a client machine (DELL Vostro 420) we experienced problems when booting: when turning on the machine beeps normal but doesn't display anything and doesn't boot.

After some testing I found out, that this only happens if one (of the two) monitors (Iiyama ProLite E2472HDD) is plugged in while booting. If the other monitor (TFT 2) is plugged in everything is fine. Here a small illustration, TFT 1 is the bad guy:

```
TFT 1 | TFT 2 | failure
  x   |   x   |     x
  x   |       |     x
      |   x   |
```

After BIOS-Phase I can safely plug in TFT 1 and everything works just fine.

The question is, what can be done to avoide this behavior:

- Change monitor? (Iiyama ProLite E2472HDD)
- Change graphics card? (GeForce 9800 GT)
- Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you boot with a working TFT and then switch the screen - what does happen? Have a look at /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/messages, maybe you will see some valuable hints there.

Comment: Please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFTP and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD - now guess ;)